# How to rewrite my url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my web  page and i want to hide all the contents inside, so the user will not see the page names. it's a php web page hosted on a linux server here is part of the code of my .htaccess file

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ''$ Something.php[L]
```

for example from www.somedomain.com/Something.php i want to look like www.somedomain.com only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways. For example, if you want to use a [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern):

```
# RewriteRule ''$ Something.php[L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok. I didn't see your last sentences. You can always create a cookie or session to manage the initial request and then redirect the user to www.somedomain.com but... why would you? In that case you have to redirect the user from your php code. For example:
    
    header('location:http://www.somedomain.com'); exit;